# Why 'os.system()' exits with return code 1?

Tags: python, r

I am receiving exit code to be 1. The os.system(r_command) doesn't seem to execute the try.R script.

```
import os

# Replace 'your_script.R' with the actual path to your R script
r_script_path = 'path/try.R'

# Build the R script execution command
r_command = f'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/bin/Rscript.exe {r_script_path}'

# Run the command and capture output and error
result = os.system(r_command)
print("Exit Code:", result)
```

I was expecting the try.R script to be executed and a new csv file to be created.

Comment: Are your sure the actual path is correct? It seems to be a relative path.

Comment: The command's quoting is wrong, if nothing else. It's trying to execute `c:/Program` -- the space between `Program` and `Files` isn't quoted or escaped to prevent it from being treated as syntax.

Comment: Anyhow, it's bad form to use `os.system` in the first place. You don't have this problem at all if you use `subprocess.call()` with the default/proper `shell=False`.

Comment: (that is to say: `result = subprocess.call(['c:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/bin/Rscript.exe', r_script_path])`, optionally also capturing stdout/stderr if you have a need to do so).

Comment: Consider saving the R bin folder in your PATH environment variable so `Rscript` (.exe not required) is a recognized command (without absolute path) just like the `python` executable.